# Loading a picture with sci-kit image displays wrong colours in image

Tags: python, image, scikit-image

I'm having problems loading my image with Python. The following is my code:

```
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = io.imread('.tif file was put here')

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Running this in the Python 3.4 shell results in my image coming up, but rather than being in its normal colour (greyscale) it shows up with rainbow-like colours. This also happens when I try to run this code for the Lena test image:

```
from scipy import misc
l = misc.lena()
misc.imsave('lena.png', l) # uses the Image module (PIL)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(l)
plt.show()
```

You can see the image output that Python displays with the wrong colours here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/veINU.png. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default colormap for `imshow()` is `jet` (you can see the list of default `matplotlib` colormaps [here](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps)). If you want grayscale, you have to specify it explicitly:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
plt.imshow(l, cmap=cm.gray)
```

*Edit:* an addition for clarity. In both of your examples images only contain the intensity information, so `imshow` uses its `cmap` parameter. If they had the full RGB(A) information, `cmap` would be ignored, and the images would be shown according to that information.

Comment: Oh, wow! Thank you so, so much! I'm very new at this, and coming into Python from a biologist background. Thanks again for your very quick and helpful response!

Comment: You could have just pressed on a tick near my answer to accept it ;)

Comment: Oh! Learning something new all the time, haha. :)

Comment: And remember! `jet` is evil! use other colormaps!